# I'm creating multiple child components using *ngFor directive, is it possible to make all the child components behave the same way?

Tags: angular, ngfor

In the example below multiple child components are created using *ngFor directive. How to make all the child components behave the same way, in this case all the child components to have same sum value when add function in one of the child function is clicked ?

app.component.html

```
<div class="app-container">
  <app-child *ngFor="let x of [1,2,3,4,5]" [id]="x"></app-child>
</div>
```

child.component.html

```
<p>child-{{id}} works!</p>
  <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
<h3>Sum={{total}}</h3>
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id:number=0;
  total:number = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  add(){
    this.total++;
  }

}
```

[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4nge.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way is to add more bindings to your child.

Instead of the child keeping track of a local variable called `total`, accept the current total as an `@Input` from the parent. Also add an `@Output` that the child will trigger to let the parent know to update the total.

The `@Output` is an [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) with type `number`. Each time its `emit()` function is called, we pass the child's `id` back to the parent to be added to the parent's `total`. Since all children accept the parent's `total` as an `@Input`, they all show the same value.

#### child.component.ts / child.component.html

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() id: number = 0;
  @Input() total: number = 0;
  @Output() added = new EventEmitter<number>();

  add() {
    this.added.emit(this.id);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>child-{{id}} works!</p>
<button (click)="add()">Add</button>
<h3>Sum={{total}}</h3>
```

#### app.component.ts / app.component.html

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  total: number = 0;

  onAdded(value: number) {
    this.total += value;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="app-container">
  <app-child *ngFor="let x of [1,2,3,4,5]" 
             [id]="x"
             [total]="total"
             (added)="onAdded($event)"
  ></app-child>
</div>
```